# NodeJs JWT Passport

Tags: node.js, jwt

I use nodejs with passport Auth JWT. I can create the JWT Token but If I secure my route with passport.authenticate('jwt')   it's not work and i have an errors.

My  Error : 
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at JwtStrategy._verify (D:\Programes\nodejs\node\CRUD_NodeAngular5\NodeServer\config\passport.js:15:39)
    at D:\Programes\nodejs\node\CRUD_NodeAngular5\NodeServer\node_modules\passport-jwt\lib\strategy.js:110:26
    at D:\Programes\nodejs\node\CRUD_NodeAngular5\NodeServer\node_modules\passport-jwt\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:27:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Passport.js

```
var JwtStrategy     = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt      = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

var User            = require('../models/User');
var config          = require('./database');
module.exports = function(passport) {
    var opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        User.findById(jwt_payload.$__._id, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                done(null, user);
            } else {
                done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
};
```

Login

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            res.send({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
            console.log('User not found');
        } else {
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
                if (isMatch && !err) {
                    var token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {expiresIn: 1000 }); 
                    var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
                    console.log(decoded);
                    res.json({ success: true, token:'JWT ' + token, decoded:  decoded });
                    console.log('Connected : ' + token);
                } else {
                    res.send({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Passwords did not match.' });
                    console.log('Password is wrong');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Route Dashboard Not work

```
router.get('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res) {
    res.send('It worked! User id is: ' );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

lets clean your code it's simple :- 
Step1: create config file and load where you keep your routes

```
var checkAuth = require('../config/check-auth');
```

Step2: copy paste it in check-auth

```
const jwt  = require('jsonwebtoken');

    module.exports = (req,res,next)=>{
    try{
        const token  = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        const decoded  = jwt.verify(token,"secret");
        req.userData = decoded;
        next();
    }catch(error){
        return res.status(401).json({message:'Auth failed'});
          }
    }
```

step 3 :protect your route

```
router.get('/dashboard',checkAuth , { session: false }), 
function(req, res) {
    res.send('It worked! User id is: ' );
});
```

protect all your routes by passing checkAuth as parameter